# Update array of object in a JSON field in drf model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm stuck at something. I've a model:

```
class DummyModel(BaseModel):

    status = {
        'Key1': None,
        'Key2': None,
        'Key3': None,
        'Key4': None,
        'key5': None
    }

    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.JSONField(default=status)
```

I'm getting data from frontend like this:

```
{
   "user": "a225e17c-153d-21b0-bde3-a32d41ac1d30",
   "status":[
    {"Key1": "Dummy"},
    {"Key2": "Dummy"}
    ] 
}
```

The question is, I need to save this data(update the existing Json) into my model. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried simply querying the row and updating the returned object?... PS, if your status values are finite, you might as well make it its own table

Comment: I think the `status` data in the frontend does not match the status data in models. The data in the frontend is the array, but the data in the backend is like the object.